# Mongodump mac vs ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-18.04, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi, mongodump

I am trying to get a dump of a specific collection from my database. In mac, I am running the following command:

`/usr/local/bin/mongodump --uri <connection_string> --db admin --collection tenants` and it works perfectly well.

However, when I try to run the same command in ubuntu, I get the following error:
`error parsing command line options: illegal argument combination: cannot specify --db and --uri`

I tried to add the /dbname suffix to the connection string but then I am not able to download a single collection as it fails with the error `Failed: bad option: cannot dump a collection without a specified database`

Replacing --uri with --host seems like another possible solution but that does not work for me since I only have the connection string and do not have access to the username and password.

Another weird thing I noticed is that in mac, the command `mongodump --version` returns:

```
MongoDB shell version v5.0.6
Build Info: {
    "version": "5.0.6",
    "gitVersion": "212a8dbb47f07427dae194a9c75baec1d81d9259",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "system",
    "environment": {
        "distarch": "x86_64",
        "target_arch": "x86_64"
    }
}
```

However, in ubuntu I am seeing `mongodump version: built-without-version-string`.

How do I get a dump of a single collection using connection string on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the installation of mongo-tools was corrupt.

Fixed it by installing using these commands

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```